# Can the JRE be compiled to and run in Web Assembly?

Tags: java, webassembly

Could the Java Runtime be compiled for the Web, given the ability to translate Java bytecode to WebAssembly, and run Java VM from the browser, *not* in an widely unsupported applet? I know there is a alternative that is both easier and faster than this (JWebAssembly), but this is more about the principle than the application. I am just curious if this could happen.

Comment: WebAssembly is, to my knowledge, turing-complete, so yes, it is possible at least in theory. I faintly remember seeing a tech demo of a WebAssembly-based JVM a couple of years ago and being snarky about it, but I can't find a link right now. At the very least, the JVM *has* been implemented in JavaScript, see https://github.com/plasma-umass/doppio. - Note that this is a reimplementation, so the approach is a bit different from your proposed approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has some significant parallels with how you can run C# within the browser using WebAssembly. Both Java & C# run within their own virtual machine, the JRE and .Net CLR respectively.

In order to run C# within WebAssembly, the Blazor project took one of the open source CLR implementations and compiled it to WebAssembly. This allows C# DLLs to run within the browser.

Exactly the same solution could be used to run Java in the browser, however, a key to this would most likely be finding a suitable open source JRE implementation that can be compiled to WebAssembly.